# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, vb.net

I  create a SQL Server database and I want to add some data in a particular table of that database. I use some textbox to input the data and an add button to complete. But when I tap the button the whole process was stopped and indicate an error in the DBSQL module which is shown below.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module DBSQLServer
    Public con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=JOYALXDESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SaleInventory;Integrated Security=True")
    Public cmd As New SqlCommand
    Public da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public dt As DataTable
    Public qr As String
    Public i As Integer

    Public Function searchdata(ByVal qr As String) As DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(qr, con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        Return ds

    End Function

    Public Function insertdata(ByVal qr As String) As Integer

        cmd = New SqlCommand(qr, con)
        con.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        Return i

    End Function
End Module
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In the table, I have 5 columns:

```
ProID, ProName, ProDesc, ProPrice, ProStock
```

`ProID` is my primary key.

Here's my add button code to add the data into the database:

```
Private Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
        If (isformvalid()) Then
            qr = "Insert into tblProductInfo (ProName, ProDesc, ProPrice, ProStock) Values('" & nametext.Text & "','" & descriptiontext.Text & "','" & pricetext.Text & "','" & stocktext.Text & "')"
            Dim logincorrect As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(insertdata(qr))
            If (logincorrect) Then
                MsgBox("Stock Added Successfully ...", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("Something Wrong. Record Not Saved. Please Check and Try Again...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

When my query is:

```
qr = "Insert into tblProductInfo (ProName, ProDesc, ProPrice, ProStock) Values('" & nametext.Text & "','" & descriptiontext.Text & "','" & pricetext.Text & "','" & stocktext.Text & "')"
```

The error is below :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProID', table 'SaleInventory.dbo.tblProductInfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

And when my query is:

```
qr = "Insert into tblProductInfo (ProID, ProName, ProDesc, ProPrice, ProStock) Values('" & idtext.Text & "','" & nametext.Text & "','" & descriptiontext.Text & "','" & pricetext.Text & "','" & stocktext.Text & "')"  `
```

Then the error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblProductInfo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblProductInfo'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: Did you forget to make the ProID column be an auto-increment column?

Comment: I am not sure. How do I check that? I currently use the Microsoft SQL server management studio.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: _How do I check that?_ In SSMS right click your table, select *Design*, select the primary key row, look at the *Column Properties* window and verify if the *Identity Specification* contains Yes for *(Is Identity)*, 1 for *Identity Seed* and 1 for *Identity Increment*

Comment: Glad to be of help, but you should really pay attention to the @marc_s comment. Never write queries in that way. I expect now problems with the Price column if you store a decimal value in a string column or viceversa if you pass a string value when a decimal value is expected. Learn how to use parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is because in  tblProductInfo  there is a row with ProID=1. You should code so that avoid this duplicate, for example you can first run a script to find the maximum of ProID in your table ("Select MAX(ProID) from tblProductInfo"), and run your query with MAX(ProID)+1.

Comment: While this should work in most cases.  It is actually best to rely on an IDENTITY column not handling the ids one's self.  If handling Ids oneself then a GUID would be a more appropriate choice in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have corrected your database making the ProdID an identity field.

Notice that all interaction with the user interface is performed in the Form code. All interaction with the database is performed in the Module. Although you still need to Import System.Data (for the DataTable type) it is not necessay to Import System.Data.SqlClient in the Form. All validation is done in the Form.

In the Module code, the Using...EndUsing blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. I have demonstrated how to use parameters to avoid Sql injection but I had to guess at the datatypes. Check your database for the actual datatypes and adjust the SqlDbType and the parameter types and the validation code in the Form accordingly.

Connections are precious resources. Notice that the connection is opened at the last minute and closed and disposed by the `End Using` immediately after it is used by and .Execute...

```vb
Module DBSQLServer
    Private conString As String = "Data Source=JOYALXDESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SaleInventory;Integrated Security=True"

    'Example of how your search function might look.
    Public Function searchdata(Name As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From tblProductInfo Where Name = @Name", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Function insertdata(Name As String, Description As String, Price As Decimal, Stock As Integer) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(conString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into tblProductInfo (ProName, ProDesc, ProPrice, ProStock) Values(@Name,@Description, @Price, @Stock", cn)
                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
                    .Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Description
                    .Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Price
                    .Add("@Stock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Stock
                End With
                cn.Open()
                i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End Using
        End Using
        Return i
    End Function
End Module
```

And in the form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'First check that  text boxes for string parameters are filled in
    If nametext.Text = "" OrElse descriptiontext.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all text boxes.")
        Return
    End If
    'Next check for valid numeric values
    Dim price As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(pricetext.Text, price) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The price must be a number.")
        Return
    End If
    Dim stock As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(stocktext.Text, stock) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Stock must be a whole number")
        Return
    End If
    Dim retVal As Integer = DBSQLServer.insertdata(nametext.Text, descriptiontext.Text, price, stock)
    If retVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Product successfully added.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt = DBSQLServer.searchdata(txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```